# JTextArea doesn't get new line \n correctly

Tags: java, swing, console, character, newline

I'm writing a reminder app which shows a specific text in a `JTextArea`. That text may be passed as `consol argument` when you start the java app or (if no argument is available) with a custom dialog with another `JTextArea` where you can type in your text.

I'd like to have a paragraph (new line) in my reminder. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the settings dialog inside the `JTextArea` it works perfectly. But when I type in `Statement1\nStatement2` it shows exactly this text instead of two lines (I can't type a <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside the consol, can I?). When I debug the code, it takes every char particulary and converts the backslash into a double backslash instead of taking the \n as one char. So the character `\n` will be splited in `\\` and `n` (--> no control sign anymore). The same thing happens from the consol with the text as argument.

I already tried `\n` and `\r\n` and even `\\n` or `\\\n`, but it takes each character particulary and converts it.

How can I achieve that Java knows that the backslash und the n are together? How can I get a new line?

Comment: I think you are already getting the escaped ```\``` from the args. You'll have to convert it there(replace \\n with \n).

Comment: I think this would be a littlebit inconvenient, but if this would work, why not. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use \n in the command line arguments as a separator, you'll have to replace it in your code, because all characters are escaped this way. 
You can try something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String formattedString = args[0].replaceAll("\\\\n","\n");
    ...
}
```

Comment: nice way to convert the escaped `\\n`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to Java. To type <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a Unix terminal, surround it with quotes, or precede it with a backslash or type <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>.

```
$ echo "hello
> world"
hello
world
```

On Windows, `cmd.exe` uses `^` as an escape code.

```
C:\>java ClassName param1^
More?                                                           (press Enter)
More? param2
```

Comment: Do you mean in Windows `cmd.exe`? It's a little different, see update.